# Remove foreign key added by convention in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities:

```
class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

class ActionLog
{
    public Guid ActionLogId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User {get; set;}
}
```

When I add those to EF Core data context a foreign key is generated by convention on ActionLog.UserId, but I would like just to log UserId without a relation. I don't want cascade deletes and key checks. How could I remove that convention?

Comment: I don't think there is such convention (and indeed it does not create FK in my test - EF Core 2.2, SqlServer). What EF Core version is this?

Comment: Is this the entire model? It looks like an excerpt. *Something* must cause EF to infer a FK. Just matching names is not enough (fortunately...).

Comment: You are right, this is excerpt. Sorry, I forgot to add User navigation property. Updated the question

Comment: OK, in that case you should just remove the `User` property. Or unmap it (but then, what's the use?).

Comment: That is the point. I want to have the User property. But I don't want a foreign key.
In my practice it is quite normal to have such relations without keys. Yes, at some point in time Users may be removed. But I want logs to stay there. Also I want to be able to write an ActionLog with arbitrary UserId, that does not exist in my database. Such things do happen.
But most of the time, the UserId is valid and I want to be able to do joins on it

Comment: You can't keep EF from generating a FK if the `User` property is mapped. Moreover, the navigation property will generate an INNER JOIN unless you make ActionLog.UserId nullable. My opinion? If you delete a user but leave its FK values in tables you may as well set the FK values to null: the FK value is totally meaningless. Or don't delete users but de-activate them so you can have trusted and non-nullable FK values.

Comment: Probably you are right, I can just make UserId nullable and it will update values to null when user is deleted

Answer (score 2):

This code removes foreign key relation with User as well as keeps UserId column without relation attached to User. Tested with ef core 6.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ActionLog>().Ignore(e => e.User);
```

Comment: Yeah, but see the comments above. What's the use?

Comment: @GertArnold In my experience for an entity I have to remove relation that comes from base class which is base for multiple entities.

Comment: Sometimes you need to be able to delete the associated data and don't want a foreign key constraint.